# How to compare peak location and tail length of two different distributions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, nonparametric

I have the distributions of the fraction of people in each income bracket in a town in 1990 and 2020. The total sample size is the same in both, and assume that the incomes have been adjusted to account for inflation.

[image]

I want to see if the following two observations (which are visible to the naked eye) are statistically significant:

1. The largest fraction of the town was making minimum wage in 1990, but that is not the case in 2020.
2. The fraction of people in the high income range have increased in 2020.

Which statistical test should I use for this? My question is mainly because I can't identify which distribution it is (I have only very basic-level statistics knowledge that deals with normal distributions).

Comment: Please explain the meaning ‘income bracket’.

Comment: Basically annual salaries grouped as 20k-30k, 30k-40k, 40k-50k etc.